# How to concatenate three tables into one table?

Tags: mysql, database, join, view

Table1 tblUserBadges

```
uid scenid  badgeid timestamp

u0    s1      b0       t1

u0    s1      b1       t2

u0    s2      b0       t3

u1    s1      b3       t4

u1    s1      b4       t5
```

Table2 tblUserWarnings

```
uid scenid  warningid   timestamp

u0    s1      w0         t1

u0    s1      w1         t2

u0    s2      w2         t3

u1    s1      w3         t4

u1   s1       w4         t5
```

Table3 tblUserScenScores

```
uid scenid  score   attempts    timestamp


u0    s1     20       3            t1


u1    s1     22       7            t2

u0    s2     -5       1            t3
```

**RESULT** : Tabl4 viewUserScenarioStats

```
uid scenid  badges   warnings   score   attempts
u0   s1     b0, b1   w0, w1      20       3

u0   s2     b0       w2          -5       1

u1   s1     b3, b4   w3, w4      22       7
```

I tried query as follow:

```
CREATE VIEW viewUserScenarioStats AS 
SELECT  uid.tblUserBadge, GROUP_CONCAT(scenid).tblUserWarnings, 
GROUP_CONCAT( badgeid).tblUserScrores, warningid.tblUserWarnings, score, attempts
```

How to concatenate three tables.
But not working.....Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so

```
select s.uid ,
s.scenid,
group_concat(distinct b.badgeid) badges,
group_concat(distinct w.warningid)  `warnings`,
s.score,
s.attempts
from tblUserScenScores s
join tblUserWarnings w on(s.uid = w.uid and s.scenid = w.scenid)
join tblUserBadges b  on(s.uid = b.uid and s.scenid = b.scenid)
group by s.uid ,s.scenid
```

[`DEMO`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/223fa/7)

[`View Demo`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/521553/1)

Comment: Can u tell me? how do u do that? Is there any tips for me? give me your secret key...

Comment: @PrashantTapase there is nothing special i have just joined your tables and then grouped results on basis of same uid ,scenid there are multiple rows from badges and warning tables for each score so using group_concat i have merged badges and warning for each score as a comma separated list but w0, w1 are appearing more than 1 so added distinct in `group_concat` to pick associated warning and badge only once i guess that makes sense for you